# Getting error while executing Spark Example using Microsoft.Net libraries

Tags: apache-spark

I have started evaluating Microsoft.Spark using CSharp as language and wrote simple program as below:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->

    // Instantiate a session
            var spark = SparkSession
                .Builder()
                .AppName("Hello Spark!")
                .GetOrCreate();

            var df = spark.Read().Json(@"%SPARK_HOME%\examples\src\main\resources\people.json");

            // Print schema
            df.PrintSchema();

            // Apply a filter and show results
            df.Filter(df["age"] > 21).Show();
```

I have installed:
Spark 2.4.1
Hadoop winutils
Apache Maven 
Microsoft.Spark.Worker

Getting below error while creating sockets:

```
 [Exception] [JvmBridge] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5567
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Network.DefaultSocketWrapper.Connect(IPAddress remoteaddr, Int32 port, String secret)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.GetConnection()
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] args)
```

[No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5567](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruidE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the resolution, when you create application in C#, it needs to be submitted to Spark using Spark-submit command like this:

```
spark-submit.cmd --class org.apache.spark.deploy.DotnetRunner --master local C:\github\dotnet-spark\src\scala\microsoft-spark-2.4.x\target\microsoft-spark-2.4.x-0.2.0.jar Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.exe Sql.Basic %SPARK_HOME%\examples\src\main\resources\people.json
```

You can refer blog [here](https://techydeveloper.wordpress.com/2019/06/09/write-your-first-program-apache-spark-in-microsoft-net-c/)